# Send a shared secret for authentication from javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, encryption

So I have a page that posts json data using ajax of input fields in a html page.

The ajax post is to a different server, the server currently checks the authorize header, and compares it with a shared key, if the key matches the json request is executed (the request is done over https).

My concern is that anyone can open the source and view the shared key, meaning anyone could send authenticated requests to my server (bad).

So then I thought about encrypting the key instead, but that just leaves me with the first problem again.

I can't do the json request from the same server (on the server side) that generates the html page, because its too slow. I have control of what gets sent, but not when it gets sent.

I'm using the ajax call because I need the data right away.

How can I create a token, that a malicious user can't fake, so I can trust that the json request came from the server / page that I expect it to come from?

Comment: Wouldn't https (instead of http) do the trick?

Comment: @barakmanos: https just ensures that the data is not tampered with *en route*, not that it isn't faked at the source.

Comment: Thanks for the extra knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments I understand your use case better: Server A will respond with an html form, after the user complete it, it will be submitted to Server B. How do you make sure that the form post to B is actually coming from the html form, and not from somewhere else?

A short lived tokens instead of a unique key will be better, but using something like nokogiri or jsdom anyone can easily parse your form and make automatic requests.

I think a captcha mechanism like [Google reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is what you are looking for. The page in the browser will request a captcha to the captcha server using a public key, the user will have to type these letters from the image, after he submit the form, Server B will validate the value with a secret.

Comment: Whats to stop a malicious user from calling the html page that generates this JWT, then calling the API with the JWT right after? It doesn't really solve the problem, it just adds an extra step to make the process harder for a malicious user, but still relatively simple to bypass. FWI: Server A is Salesforce (APEX) and server B is   C# (WEB API).

Comment: The user credentials, you get a JWT from Server A after you are authenticated.

Comment: There is no user sign in, as a form is filled out on server A, the data is sent to server B.

Comment: I think I understand your use case better now, so I'd change the answer.